# Store a custom value in a EKEvent (iPhone Calendar)

Tags: ios4, xamarin.ios, eventkit

My app integrates with the device calendar.  When a new item is added to my app we create a calendar entry for this item.  If the item is edited we need to update the calendar item.

What I do now is put a GUID in the EKEvent.Notes but obviously this is visible to the user so we add a text "do not delete".  We then search the calendar for Notes containing the GUID to find the related item.

What would be ideal is if the EKEvent had a Tag property or if there was some type of hidden field that could take a string value.  We could then store our related unique ID in this field and not clutter the user's notes field.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure of EKEvent object as I've not really used it but I just had a little look through it and I've noticed it contains a "EventIdentifier" which is "The unique identifer for the event" - is this generated automatically? If not you could use this?

Comment: It is read-only unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is it exactly what you want to do? The 'eventIdentifier' property is meant to uniquely identify an EKEvent instance. Using the EKEventStore you can look up an existing EKEvent using this identifier. It is no surprise this value is read-only.

I can imagine that you want to differentiate between events that were already in the calendar and events that your app created. My solution would be to keep a local registration of what events you added to the calendar. You could for example store this in a local SQLite database. You can refer to events in the iPhone calendar using the 'eventIdentifier' values.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Optimally if the EKEvent had a Tag property (string) that I could put a unique value into (GUID) so I could search by this hidden field and find the events my app created rather than searching for items that may have the same data.  I currently place a GUID in the Notes field but I may look at using the read only identifier and store that value in my database as you suggested as well.

Comment: what I am going to do is store these eventidentifier's in my CoreData data store so I have a reference for them - was looking for the same solution as you with the Tag to reduce the programming I'd have to do but it look like no dice.  No I'll also have to check to see if things have been removed outside of my app in the calendar or where ever.  Kind of annoying.

Comment: I wish there was a better way. This solution doesn't work when you start looking at syncing events between multiple events. I think I may need to just create a local calendar. Although that has some interesting requirements that I need to figure out

Comment: @BRogers Did you end up creating a local calendar? Seems like that solution has many of its own problems, especially when an app is used across multiple devices. I am also looking at the possibility of multiple devices using my app and trying to find the best solution for a calendar to use. What did you come up with in the end?

Comment: @JPK I actually just ended up using the default calendar and looking up the events and seeing if there's a matching event for my local db. It's not as beautiful as I'd like. But, it works

Comment: Issue with a local DB is that, once the user some how deletes the app, all the event identifiers are lost (unless that DB file was synced with iCloud). And then if he install the app again all the events get duplicated.

Comment: True. So make sure you sync with iCloud then!