# New stored property always returns nil | iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift-extensions

A new stored property created for exisiting class using extension. While getting value its always returning nil value. The below code is what i tried to add new stored property.

```
var IdentifiableIdKey   = "kIdentifiableIdKey"
extension EKEvent {
    
    public var customId: Int {
        get {
            return (objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &IdentifiableIdKey) as? Int) ?? 0
        }
        set {
            print("\(newValue)")
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &IdentifiableIdKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Utilisation

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
let calendars = eventStore.calendars(for: .event)

for calendar in calendars {
    
       if calendar.title == "Events" {
                                    
         let oneMonthAgo = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -30*24*3600)

         let oneMonthAfter = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: +30*24*3600)
                            
         let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: oneMonthAgo as Date, end: oneMonthAfter as Date, calendars: [calendar])
                            
         let events = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
                                    
           for event in events {                                        
                print("evnet id \(event.customId)")

                }
             }
          }
```

Somebody help me to find the mistake I did. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you getting its value? Are you sure you are accessing the same `EKEvent`?

Comment: I can do `let a = EKEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore());a.customId = 1;print(a.customId)` and it will print 1 as expected. What code did you use?

Comment: Check my edit @Sweeper

Comment: Aha, so you are trying to save/persist `customId` as well?

Comment: yes ............

Comment: I'm not familiar with EventKit enough to tell you whether that's possible or not. I've only used it once. But why do you need a `customId` when `EKEvent` already has `eventIdentifier`?

Comment: eventIdentifier is read-only property.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440420/store-a-custom-value-in-a-ekevent-iphone-calendar) seems like a duplicate, but I'm not familiar with event kit enough to be sure...

Comment: Well, it is a read-only property because it is set automatically by EventKit. You don't need to set it. You are not supposed to set the ID of an event. EventKit _is_. See the possible duplicate for more details.

Comment: It already added in question. @Dandelion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that `objc_getAssociatedObject/objc_setAssociatedObject` assign a value to an object instance so it can be alive with this instance only. Since your custom property is not serialised by EventKit it's naturally that new obtained instances of events after the request have no associated objects.

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: You can look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550287/how-to-add-some-additional-fields-to-ekevent. Or also you can try to make your second store e.g. dictionary that maps `eventIdentifier` to your custom data but in this way you should synchronise all changes each time programatically.

Answer (score -2):

Extensions in Swift can add **computed** instance properties and **computed** type properties only https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Comment: He added a computed instance property.

Answer (score -2):

It's called objc_setAssociatedObject. See the "Object" at the end? An Int is not an object. Turn your newValue into an NSNumber so you have an object. So that is definitely not going to work.

If your class is not an @objc class that *might* be a problem.

Comment: An `Int` is *automatically* wrapped into an `NSNumber` when passed to an Objective-C function taking an object parameter. This *does* work.

Comment: No luck with NSNumber :(